# MySQL Create Procedure Yields Error 1064

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

Good Morning,

I'm creating the following procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insert_inventory_audit`(
IN  `pitem_id`      int,
IN  `puser_id`      int,
IN  `pfield_name`   varchar(265),
IN  `pold_value`    mediumtext,
IN  `pnew_value`    mediumtext
)
BEGIN

INSERT INTO inventory_audit (item_id, user_id, field_name, old_value, new_value)
VALUES (pitem_id, puser_id, pfield_name, pold_value, pnew_value);
END$$
```

It is being copied to our new server running MySQL 5.5.19 from our old server running MySQL 5.0.45.

When I excecute the above code on the new server, I recieve the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL   
server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 11
```

Does this mean that each entry inside the VALUES parentheses must be surrounded by '' eg. 'pitem_id' ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have `DELIMITER $$` before the create statement.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't change the delimiter from the default `;`, so the `;` you're using there is actually terminating the procedure, not the query.

```
DELIMITER $$   <--- add this line
CREATE ....
...
END$$
```